# Need assistance with discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user enters the command !finduser and a username so for example "!finduser user3" I want the bot to post a website url and add "/user3" to the end like this https://ogusers.com/user3. I know its confusing but i dont really know how to explain it.
Heres the current code.

```
if message.content.startswith('!finduser'):
    user = message.content.startswith ('')
    msg = 'https://ogusers.com' + '/' + user
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question in your post. Also, the code you have provided does not provide enough context for us to help you with it. Please edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `discord.ext.commands` extension to handle most of the command parsing for you.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def finduser(ctx, name):
    await bot.say("https://ogusers.com/{}".format(name))

bot.run("TOKEN")
```